# DebugTimer design

Tags: c#, timer

**Summary:**

- I created this DebugTimer class so that I could test performance of code in a much cleaner/shorter syntax.
- Prior I was using regular timers and wrapping them all in `#if DEBUG #endif`.
- I'm relatively new to events, have I done them well?
- This is the first time planning a snippet of code to be used externally (what I mean by that is I made `DebugTimer.cs` as its own library-project and `Debugger.cs` is what would be used in the project to time things, my attempt at de-coupling).

**Advice Desired...**

- Thoughts on the DEBUG mode only part? Originally I was just going to wrap most of the code in `#if DEBUG #endif` but this proved problematic when planning it as an external library.dll since the DEBUG part listened to how I built the library and not the project it was being used in.
- Have the events been well formed? Should I add/remove any that may or may not be desirable?
- I made `Timer` a private class with a public `ITimer` interface. Looking back I'm not really sure why I did it, I think my thought process was to force the use of `DebugTimer` instead of creating an instance of `Timer` and using that (Whether that's a good reason or not is beyond me).

**DebugTimer.cs**

```
public delegate void DebugTimerHandler(ITimer sender, String TimerName);

/// <summary>
/// Allows for Debug-Mode timing with minimal lines of code required for use.
/// 1) Subscribe to the OnDebugTimerStopped and OnDebugTimerStarted events to log information.
/// 2) Use StartTimer supplying a Unique name to start a new timer.
/// 3) Use StopTimer supplying an existing timer's name to stop the timer.
/// Only executes code if built in Debug-Mode.
/// </summary>
public class DebugTimer
{
    private Boolean DebugMode { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<String, ITimer> _Timers { get; set; }
    private DebugTimerHandler _OnDebugTimerStopped { get; set; }
    private DebugTimerHandler _OnDebugTimerStarted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A timer that only executes if ran in Debug-Mode. For external library reasons,
    /// this must be passed in as a variable (otherwise it detects if the library itself was
    /// built in debug/release mode.
    /// See here for more information: 
    /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654450/programmatically-detecting-release-debug-mode-net
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="DebugMode">Use #if DEBUG #endif to detect if you're in Debug-Mode.</param>
    /// <param name="OnDebugTimerStarted">Event executed right before the timer starts.</param>
    /// <param name="OnDebugTimerStopped">Event executed right after the timer stops.</param>
    public DebugTimer(Boolean DebugMode = true, DebugTimerHandler OnDebugTimerStarted = null, DebugTimerHandler OnDebugTimerStopped = null)
    {
        this.DebugMode = DebugMode;
        if (DebugMode)
        {
            this._Timers = new Dictionary<String, ITimer>();
            this._OnDebugTimerStarted = OnDebugTimerStarted ?? delegate { };
            this._OnDebugTimerStopped = OnDebugTimerStopped ?? delegate { };
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does nothing if not compiled in Debug-Mode.
    /// </summary>
    public void StartTimer(String Timer)
    {
        if (DebugMode)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer(Timer);
            timer.DebugTimerStarted += this._OnDebugTimerStarted;
            timer.DebugTimerStopped += this._OnDebugTimerStopped;

            if (_Timers.ContainsKey(Timer))
            {
                _Timers[Timer].Start();
                //throw new Exception(String.Format("DebugTimer with the name {0} already exists!", Timer));
            }
            else
            {
                _Timers.Add(Timer, timer);
                _Timers[Timer].Start();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does nothing if not compiled in Debug-Mode.
    /// </summary>
    public void StopTimer(String Timer)
    {
        if (DebugMode)
        {
            if (_Timers.ContainsKey(Timer))
            {
                _Timers[Timer].Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private class Timer : ITimer
    {
        private String Name { get; set; }
        private Stopwatch _Stopwatch { get; set; }

        public long Miliseconds
        {
            get
            {
                return _Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            }
        }
        public long Ticks
        {
            get
            {
                return _Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
            }
        }

        #region Events
        public event DebugTimerHandler DebugTimerStopped;
        protected virtual void OnDebugTimerStopped(String TimerName)
        {
            if (DebugTimerStopped != null)
                DebugTimerStopped(this, TimerName);
        }

        public event DebugTimerHandler DebugTimerStarted;
        protected virtual void OnDebugTimerStarted(String TimerName)
        {
            if (DebugTimerStarted != null)
                DebugTimerStarted(this, TimerName);
        }
        #endregion

        public Timer(String Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this._Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _Stopwatch.Reset();
            OnDebugTimerStarted(this.Name);
            _Stopwatch.Start();
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            _Stopwatch.Stop();
            OnDebugTimerStopped(this.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Debugger.cs:**

```
public static class Debugger
{
    #if DEBUG
        static Boolean DebugMode = true;
    #else
        static Boolean DebugMode = false;
    #endif

    public static DebugTimer Timer = new DebugTimer(DebugMode, PreLog, PostLog);

    private static void PreLog(ITimer sender, String TimerName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}...", TimerName);
    }
    private static void PostLog(ITimer sender, String TimerName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Milliseconds: {1} Ticks: {2}\n...{0}", TimerName, sender.Miliseconds, sender.Ticks);
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
Debugger.Timer.StartTimer("Testing");

for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
{
    Debugger.Timer.StartTimer("++i");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {

    }
    Debugger.Timer.StopTimer("++i");

    Debugger.Timer.StartTimer("i++");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {

    }
    Debugger.Timer.StopTimer("i++");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Debugger.Timer.StopTimer("Testing");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) input parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing.

> ```
> public DebugTimer(Boolean DebugMode = true, DebugTimerHandler OnDebugTimerStarted = null, DebugTimerHandler OnDebugTimerStopped = null)
> ```

should be

```
public DebugTimer(Boolean debugMode = true, DebugTimerHandler onDebugTimerStarted = null, DebugTimerHandler onDebugTimerStopped = null)
```

this

> ```
> public delegate void DebugTimerHandler(ITimer sender, String TimerName);
> ```

should be

```
public delegate void DebugTimerHandler(ITimer sender, String timerName);
```

Propertynames shouldn't start with an underscore `_` either. This should be used for classmember variables only. One would either use `_someVariable`, `mSomeVariable` or just `someVariable` for a classmember variable, but always `SomeVariable` for a property name.

---

Sometimes you are using `this.` to refer to a class property, sometimes you aren't. You should stick to one style and not mixing them.

---

Using private properties (getter and setter are private) is only adding noise to the code. There isn't a real benefit of using them if you hadn't some validation logic etc. in the setter.

---

> ```
> public void StartTimer(String Timer)
> {
>     if (DebugMode)
>     {
>         Timer timer = new Timer(Timer);
> ```

this just smells. Using a variable name which is the same as an existing,used class.

---

Commented code like `//throw new Exception(String.Format("DebugTimer...` is dead code which only adds noise and should be deleted.

---

By adding a guard clause like

```
if (!DebugMode) { return; }
```

you will reduce horizontal spaceing and therefor add readability.

---

> ```
> public void StartTimer(String Timer)
> {
>     if (DebugMode)
>     {
>         Timer timer = new Timer(Timer);
>         timer.DebugTimerStarted += this._OnDebugTimerStarted;
>         timer.DebugTimerStopped += this._OnDebugTimerStopped;
>
>         if (_Timers.ContainsKey(Timer))
>         {
>             _Timers[Timer].Start();
>             //throw new Exception(String.Format("DebugTimer with the name {0} already exists!", Timer));
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             _Timers.Add(Timer, timer);
>             _Timers[Timer].Start();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Instead of creating the `Timer` object first and then checking if the name of the timer is present in the dictionary, you should create the timer if it does not exists and the start it.

```
public void StartTimer(String timerName)
{
    if (!DebugMode) { return; }

    if (!_Timers.ContainsKey(timerName))
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(timerName);
        timer.DebugTimerStarted += this._OnDebugTimerStarted;
        timer.DebugTimerStopped += this._OnDebugTimerStopped;

        _Timers.Add(timerName, timer);    
    }

    _Timers[timerName].Start();

}
```

---

You should use `braces` for single statements `if` statements too which makes your code less error prone.

If you decide to not use `braces` in these cases, you should stick the the choosen style. Right now you are mixing the styles.

---

Timing methods will only be accurate, if compiled in release mode.

See also my answer here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/80051/29371 about `ProcessorAffinity` and `PriorityClass` of the current process.

---

Usually an event has a signature like `(object sender...` instead of `(ITimer sender...` but this isn't a issue.

---

The private vs. public scope of the `Timer` class is a little bit more tricky. This is mostly because `DebugTimer` is only pretending by its name to be a timer but is in reality only holding a collection of different timers.

A better (and more OO) approach would be to create a `DebugTimer` class which implements `ITimer` and uses the `Timer` class by composition. This `DebugTimer` class should contain the `DebugMode` property, so you also could add a `ReleaseTimer` class without this property.

Both timer classes could then be contained in a `Timing` class which holds a `Dictionary<string, ITimer>` and having a `AddTimer()` and `RemoveTimer()` method.

Comment: I am really-really bad at pascal-casing parameters haha. I never learned the C# naming conventions until I had already used it a significant amount haha. I try.

Thanks for the feedback, it is helpful. I was aware of the whole `object sender` part but wasn't really sure if I was supposed to keep it `object` or make it `ITimer` since it was the only sender I was going to be using for that delegate/event.